# Local variables in dispatch queue call on iOS cause intermittent crashes

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

I have an app that does some background processing... to update the progress bar not he main thread I call a method using:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
            [self updateProgress];
                   });
```

I get EXEC_BAD_ACCESS on this line:

```
 int secs=[nowDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startTransmitDate];
```

Heres the method:

```
-(void)updateProgress
{
    [mainProgressBar setProgress:((float)dataOffset/(float)totalToSend)];
    NSDate *nowDate=[NSDate date];
    int secs=[nowDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startTransmitDate];
    if(secs>0){
        float bps=(float)dataOffset/(float)secs*(float)8.0;
        bps=bps/(float)1024.0; // k
        bps=bps/(float)1024.0; // M
        if(bpsLabelText){
            speedLabel.text=nil;
            [bpsLabelText release];
            bpsLabelText=nil;
        }
        bpsLabelText=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.1fMb/s",bps];
        [bpsLabelText retain];
        speedLabel.text=bpsLabelText;
    }
}
```

StartTransmitDate is declared in the class implementation... and set elsewhere:

```
startTransmitDate=[NSDate date];
 [startTransmitDate retain];
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: BTW, instead of using `int` to store you `secs` variable, try using `NSTimeInterval` instead, which is a `double`.

Comment: Do you get any errors if you enable zombies?

Answer (score 0):

How startTransmitDate is initialized? If it is not retained anywhere did you initialized it with __block to retain it until the block stop using it?

Comment: startTransmitDate is a global in the class, is retained too.

Comment: When the app crashes can you see if startTransmitDate and nowDate are pointing to a valid value?

Answer (score 0):

Could you be missing the nowDate declaration?

```
NSDate *nowDate = [NSDate date]
```

Comment: Nope - sorry - I even declared that in the class. hence the code. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a weird idea.  Try declaring all of your local instance variables *without* initializers at the very top of the block, then initialize them only after all instance variables have been declared.  If the behavior changes, you may have found a bug!